# Implementing location based application android

Tags: android, google-maps, location-based

I am trying to make a android app where I want to show the location of user and the places to visit around that location. Let's say for example I am around certain location and I want to discover popular places around me, so how  should I start I have no idea where to begin with ? any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Foursquare API to get popular places info based on User location. http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

To get User Location , you should read android official document. http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html